# How to create object from json string using json from url and insert into html

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have this example and need to understand how to parse the json string from a url rather than inside the html as shown. In essence..I need other easier ways of parsing the text from a url source eg. http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/pipe.run?_id=e4e173cf75b0aa1b374b7987398d6091&_render=json&_callback=getYahooFeed

How can jquery be used too? If possible, iteration of the strings/arrays can be demonstrated too.

```
            <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
        <body>
        <h2>Create Object from JSON String</h2>
        <p>
        First Name: <span id="fname"></span><br> 
        Last Name: <span id="lname"></span><br> 
        </p> 
        <script>
        var txt = '{"employees":[' +
        '{"firstName":"John","lastName":"Doe" },' +
        '{"firstName":"Anna","lastName":"Smith" },' +
        '{"firstName":"Peter","lastName":"Jones" }]}';

        obj = JSON.parse(txt);

        document.getElementById("fname").innerHTML=obj.employees[1].firstName 
        document.getElementById("lname").innerHTML=obj.employees[1].lastName 
        </script>
        </body>
        </html>
```

Comment: Where is this URL coming from, and what does it look like ?

Comment: is that and ajax response? is the url containing data or what? What exactly is it like?

Comment: sorry about url part that confused you. I mean the source of the json file eg. http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/pipe.run?_id=e4e173cf75b0aa1b374b7987398d6091&_render=json&_callback=getYahooFeed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at how [to extract querystring param](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript) and parse it through  [jQuery's parseJSON](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsejson/)

Comment: Link-only answers are highly discouraged on SO.  Links rot and become useless.